# Local Polynomial Regression: Reading nearest neighbor smoothing constants from R code

Tags: r

I'm studying from a textbook on data mining and I can't figure out how the author reads the nn values from the gcv output. The code and output are below:

```r
## cv 
alpha <- seq(0.20, 1, by = 0.01) 
n1 = length(alpha) 
g = matrix(nrow = n1, ncol = 4)
for (k in 1:length(alpha)) {
  g[k,] <- gcv(NOx ~ lp(EquivRatio, nn = alpha[k]), data = ethanol)
} 
g
```

[image]

the csv file is here:
https://github.com/jgscott/ECO395M/blob/master/data/ethanol.csv

I'm usin locfit library in R.

How do you find with given output?

Comment: What package do you use? Where does the dataset `ethanol` come from? Please specify these in your question.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Corrected. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `nn` values are not read from the output - they are given in the input. In the loop, `nn` is assigned as the *kth* value of the object `alpha`.

Let's look at the output of the first 16 rows of `g`, which is the same as the picture you included in your question:

```r
g[1:16,]
#>            [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#>  [1,] -3.220084 18.81266 16.426487 0.1183932
#>  [2,] -3.249601 17.61614 15.436227 0.1154507
#>  [3,] -3.319650 16.77004 14.752039 0.1151542
#>  [4,] -3.336464 15.44404 13.889209 0.1115457
#>  [5,] -3.373011 14.52391 13.115430 0.1099609
#>  [6,] -3.408908 13.96789 12.634934 0.1094681
#>  [7,] -3.408908 13.96789 12.634934 0.1094681
#>  [8,] -3.469254 12.99316 11.830996 0.1085293
#>  [9,] -3.504310 12.38808 11.283837 0.1078784
#> [10,] -3.529167 11.93838 10.928859 0.1073628
#> [11,] -3.546728 11.46960 10.516520 0.1065792
#> [12,] -3.552238 11.26372 10.322329 0.1061728
#> [13,] -3.576083 11.03575 10.135243 0.1062533
#> [14,] -3.679128 10.54096  9.662613 0.1079229
#> [15,] -3.679128 10.54096  9.662613 0.1079229
#> [16,] -3.699044 10.46534  9.578396 0.1082955
```

Note that rows 11, 12 and 13 were created inside your loop using `alpha[11]`, `alpha[12]` and `alpha[13]`. These values were passed to the `nn` argument of `lp`. If you want the `nn` values included in your table, all you need to do is:

```r
cbind(g, nn = alpha)
#>                                                  nn
#>  [1,]  -3.220084 18.812657 16.426487 0.1183932 0.20
#>  [2,]  -3.249601 17.616143 15.436227 0.1154507 0.21
#>  [3,]  -3.319650 16.770041 14.752039 0.1151542 0.22
#>  [4,]  -3.336464 15.444040 13.889209 0.1115457 0.23
#>  [5,]  -3.373011 14.523910 13.115430 0.1099609 0.24
#>  [6,]  -3.408908 13.967891 12.634934 0.1094681 0.25
#>  [7,]  -3.408908 13.967891 12.634934 0.1094681 0.26
#>  [8,]  -3.469254 12.993165 11.830996 0.1085293 0.27
#>  [9,]  -3.504310 12.388077 11.283837 0.1078784 0.28
#> [10,]  -3.529167 11.938379 10.928859 0.1073628 0.29
#> [11,]  -3.546728 11.469598 10.516520 0.1065792 0.30
#> [12,]  -3.552238 11.263716 10.322329 0.1061728 0.31
#> [13,]  -3.576083 11.035752 10.135243 0.1062533 0.32
#> [14,]  -3.679128 10.540964  9.662613 0.1079229 0.33
#> [15,]  -3.679128 10.540964  9.662613 0.1079229 0.34
#> [16,]  -3.699044 10.465337  9.578396 0.1082955 0.35
```